# Can you remove SQL Server from an Azure SQL VM?

Tags: azure, azure-sql

I am migrating our SQL Server (Web 2017) instance our of our Azure VM (Windows Server 2019) into Azure SQL. After this I obviously do not want to be paying for SQL Server on the VM any more.

The VM also acts as a web server so I would prefer not to have to set up a new VM to replace it. Removing SQL Server would be the ideal solution. Uninstalling isn't an issue; but I do not know how to tell Azure not to bill us for it any more!

I know that when you add SQL Server to an existing VM you need to register it with the [SQL Server VM Resource Provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-register-with-resource-provider?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash), so I presume it is just a case of de-registering it, but I haven't had any luck finding any documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unregister the provider to stop paying for it, this is documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-register-with-resource-provider?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash#unregister-vm-from-rp)

You effectively delete the SQL VM resource, which does not delete the actual VM.

Comment: I swear I googled the exact title of that post and only got results for **registering** SQL server! Thank you for doing better searching then me